# Snaps File Eating Disc Free Space

Tags: hard-drive

Snaps Folder Gone From 1.8 Gb To 2.1 Gb
Eating Disc Free Space Have It To Retain Only 2
Of Each File In This Folder But Still Growing Larger
Eating Disc Free Space In Disc Usage Analyzer ?

Comment: Not sure I would call 3Mb " Eating" I would keep an eye on it.

Comment: Snaps have a lot of advantages and are designed to meet a lot of needs...but one of the costs is larger storage consumption.

Comment: I disagree. Snaps are the bane of modern Linux. If that insanity goes on very much longer, I'll be off to some other system (BSD?).

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: Ever Since My System Build With A Fresh Copy Of  Ubuntu 20.04.1 After System Updates My Disc Free Space When Checking With Disc Usage Analyzer Has Gone From 974.1 GB To 972.2 Did Sudo Apt Get Clean And Used Bleach Bit As A Root Does System Updates Consume Disc Free Space ?

Comment: Also No Added Software Or Changes To The System But System Updates